# SAML,how sp know where the Artifact Resolution Service endpoint is?

Tags: xml, single-sign-on, tableau-api, saml-2.0

Something about SAML.
In this [article](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/sp-initiated-single-sign-on-postartifact-bindings),a section:
The SP's Assertion Consumer Service now sends a SAML message containing the artifact to the IdP's Artifact Resolution Service endpoint. This exchange is performed using a synchronous SOAP message exchange.

But I just wonder ,it did not define the location of Artifact Resolution Service endpoint any where in SP,how does SP know where to send?

I have just made a test about saml sso of tableau,my system act as a IDP,when my idp send redirect to the ASSERTION CONSUMER SERVICE of sp(tableau server),it never call the Artifact Resolution Service of my idp,so i am confused.

here is some code I copy from internet:

```
public class SingleSignOnServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SingleSignOnServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.sendRedirect(SPConstants.ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE + "?SAMLart=AAQAAMFbLinlXaCM%2BFIxiDwGOLAy2T71gbpO7ZhNzAgEANlB90ECfpNEVLg%3D");
    }

}
```

I just copy ,do not know what is "SAMLart" and "AAQAAMF...0ECfpNEVLg%3D" are and how to change them,is this the cause that sp do not call  Artifact Resolution?I have give the idp`s metadata to sp,but it does not contain artifact resolution location,and seems I can not add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends on the SAML metadata. Your SP should have the metadata of the IdP it is working with and the IdP's metadata will tell the SP where the Artefact Resolution Service is located. e.g.

```
<ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://idp.com/artifactresolution" index="0"/>
```